# Prove that polynomial is always greater than zero

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial such that $p(1) = 0$ and $p'(x) > p(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$ , then we have to prove $p(x) > 0$, for all $x >1$.

I got it when I thought it logically . But how can we prove it mathematically.

According to me $p'(1)$ should be positive .

So after $ x= 1$ the polynomial will be positive and hence the $p'(x)$ cannot be negative i.e the polynomial is decreasing as polynomial is positive. Hence polynomial is always positive.

But how can we prove it mathematically that the polynomial is always positive . I am not getting any idea  .

Comment: Suppose there is one or more zeroes of the polynomial for some $x \gt 1$.  Call the smallest such value $y$.  Can you show that $p(x) \ge 0$  for $x \in [1,y]$ and so $p'(x) \gt 0$ for $x \in [1,y]$ and so $p(y) \gt p(1)=0$ to give a contradiction?

Comment: @Henry i cannot show it mathematically

Comment: @DanielV why it is a good thing

Comment: @DanielV read my edited question with my thinking

Comment: So it turns out to be [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).  There is no polynomial meeting the pre-conditions $p(1) = 0$ and $p'(x) > p(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$, and so all polynomials meeting the pre-conditions satify the claim, having $p(x) > 0$, for all $x >1$.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have done at last . I don't know which all polynomial are satisfying , but I have proved it . [image]

Comment: This is Motyla's answer.

Comment: Then as $p'(x)/p(x)$ tends to $0$, there is an $X$ such that for all $x>X$, $p'(x)/p(x)<1/2$, which implies $(p'(x)-p(x))/p(x)<-1/2$. The ratio of two positives that gives a negative.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a function $h(x) = p(x) e^{-x} ,$ we have $h' (x) =e^{-x} (p'(x) -p(x) )>0 $ for $x>1$ thus $h$ is increasing and therefore $h(x)>h(1) $ for $x>1.$

Comment: But  it is a polynomial function

Comment: Let $h(2)=p(2)e^{-2}$, a positive number. As $p(x)e^{-x}$ tends to zero, there is an $X>2$ such that $p(X)<h(2)/2$ and the fuction "increases" from $h(2)$ to $h(2)/2$. Ex falso quodlibet.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false.

$p(x)-p'(x)$  and $p(x)$ have the same leading term, so if the first polynomial remains negative, the second must eventually become negative.

Comment: Why leading coefficient should be negative

Comment: @koolman: I have completely rephrased. Please show me a polynomial such that $p'(x)>p(x)$.

Comment: Why second must become negative

Comment: @koolman: please show me a polynomial such that $p'(x)>p(x)$.

Comment: read my edited question with my thoughts

Comment: @koolman: your additional explanations are confuse but in any case wrong. Or show me a polynomial such that $p'(x)>p(x)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the claim may be vacuously true, in that no polynomial with the stated conditions exists.  Such a polynomial would have to grow exponentially fast for $x > 1$.

Comment: @DanielV: yep, it is vacuously true, and any proof can do.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x) > f(x)$ and $f(x)$ is positive, then $f$ grows at least exponentially fast, not polynomial.

Comment: Why exponentially

Comment: With exponential growth, $f'(x) = k ~f(x)$.  This is growing even faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x), g(x)$ are two polynomials, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ if deg $g(x)>\deg f(x)$. If same degree the limit will be the ratio of their leading coefficients. If $f(x)$ has higher degree than $g(x)$ then the limit will be $\pm\infty$, according as signs of leading terms being same or not. As derivative of a polynomial  has lower degree the question can be settled.

Comment: But this is only when x is at infinity , what about te intermediate

Comment: Think about it. You want a statement for all $x>1$, a set extending to infinity.  If the limit says something cannot you make some relevant deductions?

Comment: Can you explain it more how it satisfy for all values of x

Comment: As $p'(x)/p(x)\to 0$ , (while $x\to \infty$ ) then for given $\epsilon >0$(say 1/2) there is some $N$ such that for all  $x>N$ the  ratio $p'(x)/p(x)<\epsilon$. So $p'(x)> p(x)$ for $x>1$ is false. So one can't find a polynomial satisfying your hypothesis.

Comment: Put in simple words: If two polynomials have positive leading coefficients, then higher degree one will eventually over take the other and remain so till infinity. So your hypothesis is untenable. I am downvoting your question.

Comment: I guess op meant to say derivative is always positive. Or else he meant any continuous function

Comment: If the hypothesis is like **linear function has 3 maxima**  I can prove that it will have at least two minima. But show me a linear function with three maxima. That is the problem we are having with this question.  Unsatisfiable hypothesis.